# Can someone explain this bit wise operation

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am trying to understand what is happening in this bitwise operation that is used to set the size of a char array but I do not fully understand it.

```
unsigned long maxParams = 2;// or some other value, I just chose 2 arbitrarily

unsigned char m_uParamBitArray[(((maxParams) + ((8)-1)) & ~((8)-1))/8];
```

What size is this array set to based on the value of maxParams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This counts the number of 8-bit chars needed to fit `maxParams` bits.

`+7` is to round up to the next multiple of 8.

0 -> 7 will round to 0 char

1 -> 8 will round to 1 char

After division by 8. Which is done by `/8`

The bitwise and is to discard the last three bits before dividing by 8.

Answer (score 2):

When `maxParams` is not divisible by eight, the first part of the formula formula rounds it up to the next multiple of eight; otherwise, it leaves the number unchanged. The second part of the formula divides the result by eight, which it can always do without getting a remainder.

In general, if you want to round up to `N` without going over it, you can add `N-1` before the division:

```
(x + (N - 1)) / N
```

You can safely drop the `& ~((8)-1)` part of the expression:

```
(maxParams + (8-1))/8
```